# Does Cassandra's limitation of 2 billion cells per partition includes the replicated rows (cells) from other partitions?

Tags: cassandra, nosql

Cassandra allows upto 2 billion cells per partition. If I have 2 node cluster, with a replication factor of 2, does that mean 2 billion cells will take into account the rows redundantly save from the other node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the replication factor does not affect this limit. The limitation is **not** 2 billion/RF.

HTH, Cheers,
Carlo